# How can I determine the outcome of a scheduled report in Jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

If I use the Jasper API (5.1) to submit a request to schedule a report to run, what's the best way to determine the outcome of that scheduled event? i.e. Did the job run? Did it succeed or did it fail?

I can't see a pre-canned dashboard in Jasper's UI nor does there appear to be an API call that will give the status of a scheduled job (so scheduled to run, in progress, completed).

Seems an obvious requirement which leads me to believe there must be a way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 5.2 or 5.5 and use rest_v2 api. You can download web services guide from [docs page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation).
We are using 5.5 version of api for asynchronous report execution, it wasn't possible with 5.1 and older versions (at least we couldn't get it to work, job info would disappear few seconds after it finished).